# IOS Updating button title and updating array with button value?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to IOS Development and am implementing IOS QUIZ App.

How to update question and answers in QUIZ app.

Please check below my code this is how I am displaying.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var prevBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nxtBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var qstnlbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var answerABtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerBBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerCBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerDBtn: UIButton!

    let questions = ["How many days are there in 1 year?", "Favorite color?", "Where was I born?"]
    let answers = [["360", "365", "384", "377"], ["blue", "black", "green", "orange"], ["Tokyo", "New York", "Tennessee", "rajahmundry"]]

    //Variables
    var currentQuestion = 0
    var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0
    var points = 0;

    //Label
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

    //Button
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            print ("RIGHT!")
            points += 1
        }
        else
        {
            print ("WRONG!!!!!!")
        }

        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func preAction(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {


        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
       currentQuestion =  currentQuestion - 1


    }
    @IBAction func nxtaction(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }

       currentQuestion =  currentQuestion + 1

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        newQuestion()
    }

    //Function that displays new question
    func newQuestion()
    {
        qstnlbl.text = questions[currentQuestion]

        rightAnswerPlacement = arc4random_uniform(3)+1

        //Create a button
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()

        var x = 1

        for i in 1...4
        {
            //Create a button
            button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][x], for: .normal)
                            x = 2

        }
        currentQuestion += 1
    }
```

based on user selection answers has be to added to answerArray.

For Ex: if user selects  in first question in answerABtn  answer  option "A " answerArray has to update with "A" value.

user can able to update answer

for Ex: user select 1st question answer option "b" answerArray has to update with "b" value.

please help me out to make this quiz app.

[quiz app ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uzgg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uzgg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things you should be doing differently, but to get you on your way...

You will want to create a `answerArray` variable to hold the user-selected answers. Inside your `action` func, you are already tracking which button was tapped, so append the button's title to your answer array at the same point.

Your current `previous` and `next` actions don't make any sense, because you are not tracking the question count correctly, and you are picking a random "correct" answer each time.

Here is your code, modified for:

- better question count incrementing
- tracking user selected answers in `answerArray`
- clearing the screen when the quiz is complete

Note: this is just example code... this should not be considered "everything fixed" -- but it should help you with this step. Review the comments I've added to your code.

```
class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var prevBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nxtBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var qstnlbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var answerABtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerBBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerCBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerDBtn: UIButton!

    let questions = ["How many days are there in 1 year?", "Favorite color?", "Where was I born?"]
    let answers = [["360", "365", "384", "377"], ["blue", "black", "green", "orange"], ["Tokyo", "New York", "Tennessee", "rajahmundry"]]

    //Variables
    var currentQuestion = 0
    var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0
    var points = 0;

    // array to hold answers
    var answerArray: [String] = [String]()

    //Label
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

    //Button
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        // make sure this came from a button, and get the button title
        guard let btn = sender as? UIButton,
            let btnTitle = btn.currentTitle else { return }

        if (btn.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            print ("RIGHT!")
            points += 1
        }
        else
        {
            print ("WRONG!!!!!!")
        }

        // append the selected answer to the answerArray
        answerArray.append(btnTitle)

        // increment question counter
        currentQuestion += 1

        // if there are more questions
        if (currentQuestion < questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
        else
        {
            quizComplete()
        }

    }

    func quizComplete() -> Void {
        [answerABtn, answerBBtn, answerCBtn, answerDBtn].forEach {
            $0?.isHidden = true
        }
        qstnlbl.text = "Your score: \(points)"
    }

    // these two funcs do not make any sense as written
/*
    @IBAction func preAction(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
        currentQuestion =  currentQuestion - 1
    }
    @IBAction func nxtaction(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
        currentQuestion =  currentQuestion + 1
    }
*/

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        newQuestion()
    }

    //Function that displays new question
    func newQuestion()
    {
        qstnlbl.text = questions[currentQuestion]

        rightAnswerPlacement = arc4random_uniform(3)+1

        for i in 1...4
        {
            // get a reference to a button
            let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][i-1], for: .normal)

        }

        // don't increment question count here
        // increment it AFTER user answers the question (in button tap action)
        //currentQuestion += 1
    }

}
```

Comment: how to work with previous button and next button.. if user come from second button to first button if he update answer that answer has to update in answer array

Comment: @vasuk - well, that's something you have to work on. Right now, your code is selecting a random answer as the "correct" answer (which doesn't make much sense to begin with). So you either need to track the random correct answers, or have another part of your data identifying the actual correct answer. When the user goes Previous or Next, get the actual correct answer. If you want to allow previous so the user can *change* his answer, you need to update the correct index in your answer array instead of appending a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var emptyArray : [String] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .red

  }

  @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    emptyArray.append("A")
    print(emptyArray)
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 300, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    button.setTitle("Name your Button ", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
  }

}
```

[image]

when you press the buttom over and over, the output to debug window is this

```
["A"]
["A", "A"]
["A", "A", "A"]
["A", "A", "A", "A"]
```